# LibGDX issue with gravity and delta time

Tags: java, time, libgdx, gravity, delta

I'm having an issue related to gravity and delta time in LibGDX.
I substract 9.81 from the player's velocity every frame, and after the collision checking I add his velocity multiplied with the delta time to his position.

```
vel.y -= 9.81f;
... Collision stuff ...
pos.add(vel.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), vel.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

But the problem is that this only works fine with a set framerate of 60.
When I limit it to 30, or max it out the player falls more slowly, or much faster which really shouldn't be the case as I'm using delta time, right?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you're not using DeltaTime when you subtract the 9.81.

Comment: I recommend this article: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/ or alternatively this one http://buildnewgames.com/gamephysics/

Comment: Yeah, but I use it when I add it to the position. And when I change it how you said, still same effect.

Comment: Oh, i got it. Thanks domdom, great article!